# How to plot this type of "binary matrix" graphic (I honestly don't know if it has a name) using PHP and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, plot, graph-visualization

I'm trying to plot this type of "binary matrix" graphic:
[image: dts]

Disregard the two colors from the sample image; I want to either color a dot blue for, let's say, "complete" values or leave it uncolored/gray for "incomplete" values as a way to track daily task completion for a certain amount of dots/days. The dots represent a day where a task was completed or not completed. Showing the full amount of dots/days gives perspective on % of completion as days go by.

I would like to use a combination of HTML/Javascript and PHP + MySQL. But the hardest part for me is figuring out a good algorithm to render this visualization. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just treat each dot like it's a pixel. Also, imagine that the image has been rotated 90° CCW. Then, you simply draw a square that takes up less room that is allocated to it - this way, you get the separating lines.

Here'e a quick something to have a play with. 
A few notes:

- 0) I just halved your image dimensions
- 1) 4 pixels and 5 pixels were chosen arbitrarily
- 2) I didn't bother with setting the colour of the dot - you can
  easily do this.
- 3) I've simply treated the drawing area like a normal top-bottom
  bitmap, while your image seems to show that all of the Y values will
  be used before the next X value is needed. (This is like a 90° CCW
  rotation).
- 4) I'm addressing the pixels with an X and a Y - perhaps you'd be
  more interested in addressing them with a single number? If so, you
  could easily write a function that would map two coords to a single
  number - the pixels index, if you like.

I.e if an image is 100 x 100, there are 10,000 pixels. You could address them by specifying a number from 0 - 9,999
E.g

```
function 10k_to_100x100(index)
{
   var x = index % 100;
   var y = (index / 100).toFixed(0);
   plotPixelDot(x, y);
}
```

X is simply the remainder when dividing by the width
Y is the whole number answer when dividing by the width

Here's a snippet you can try right here on the page:

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
 var x, y;
 
 for (y=0; y<20; y++)
 {
  for (x=0; x<100; x++)
  {
   drawDot(x, y, 'output');
  }
 }
}

function drawDot(xPos, yPos, canvasId)
{
 var actualX=xPos*5, actualY=yPos*5;
 var ctx = byId(canvasId).getContext('2d');
 ctx.fillRect(actualX, actualY, 4, 4);
}
```

```html
<canvas width=558 height=122 id='output'></canvas>
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks so much!